# Backbone JS conceptualization: I'm refactoring a menus app to use Backbone.js: what views/models should I use?

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am taking the lead on refactoring a school lunch menus app to use backbone.js instead of just server-rendered html and jquery: http://tinyurl.com/74nlsu5 .  I've never done front-end MVC before, and I'm having trouble figuring out conceptually what the views/models/collections would be.

Can someone take a look at the site and recommend what some of the models/views/collections would be?  Conceptualizing a full menu site like this is a bit more complex than a simple TODO or many of the examples I've seen, so a kickstart would be much appreciated to make sure i get started on the right foot.

Comment: Tip#1 It is hard to visualize, confusing to implement a nested relationship with backbone ex; `Menu->MenuItems->[MenuItem,MenuItem]` where each `MenuItem->SubMenuItems->[MenuItem,MenuItem..]` so you would deduce MenuItem to be model and MenuItems to be collection. But problem has just begun (if you try it you will understand). Rather than doing this **I Suggest to use a robust Menu jQueryplugin that could turn your model collection to menu??**

Comment: Luckily, I have some experience writing jQuery plugins (assuming there isn't already one that is a fit), so thanks for the tip about the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really really hard to provide answers to making **FULL Site** with Backbone in my answer. So I would provide you with these tips, see what applies to your site and modify them to your liking.( I think you will be spending more time now on SO asking Backbone questions)

#### Tip #1

Ask a designer to put storyboard of site [example1](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2952-lessons-learned-from-implementing-highrises-custom-fields-feature) and [example2](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2431-basecamp-home-page-redesign)

#### Tip #2

From the storyboard draw Grid's putting each functional module as a MVC component [example](http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-1)

#### Tip #3

Refine your models, collections to consumable and maintainable number. Then refine some more. From my experience the pages i developed never had more than 3 models and two collections.

#### Tip #4

Reuse, Reuse and Reuse again. Server resources and DB call's are costly (unless implemented intelligently with caching, indexing and clever programming). Opt for client localStorage caching use scripts such as [Kizzy](https://github.com/ded/Kizzy), use same models to display different views

#### Tip #5

All customers want is solution to their problem. Don't through a philosophy at them. UX design does not matter the most i have come across sites which were looking extremely simple and really awesome at doing the job. ( I got no time to look at your fancy jingling bananas[means all fancy animations, shiny buttons], but other dev's do)

#### Tip #6

Sit with single model,view and collection finish it. Try the UI with what ever you think customer will do( not you, not even your manager) your intention here is to find quirks. I noted that signup for newsletter appends validation message each time i click signup

#### Tip #7

Never assume any views existing in the html sent from server. Views should be **self containing**

have anything more you want me to answer i will add them here :)

Comment: Thanks a ton!  This will definitely get me started on the right path.  I realized it was an unconventional SO question, but sometimes just figuring out how to go from the examples to a real-world project with new technology is the hardest part.